# XAML/C# - Auto hub from JSON

Tags: c#, json, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

How can I automatically create a hub based on the contents of a JSON file in XAML/C#? My JSON will look something like this:

```js
[
  {
    "Title": "All Things Go",
    "Length": "4:53",
    "Features": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "Title": "I Lied",
    "Length": "5:04",
    "Features": "N/A"
  }
]
```

I then want to automatically create a hub for each of the objects and then add the information in there. Does anybody know how or if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is a JSON file named "test.json" contains the content you showed above and located inside "Assets" folder in the project. The "test.json" file is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "Title": "All Things Go",
    "Length": "4:53",
    "Features": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "Title": "I Lied",
    "Length": "5:04",
    "Features": "N/A"
  }
]
```

And now we are going to create a [Hub](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/hub) control from this JSON file. To do this, firstly need to read items one by one from this JSON file(we can read it into an entity here I create a `Hubcontrol` class), secondly need to set these items as properties for [`HubSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hubsection)  and then add `HubSection` to Hub control. So example code as follows:

XAML code

```
<Page
 ...
 mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="root">    
</Grid>
</Page>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFile jsonfile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/test.json"));
        string jsonString = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(jsonfile);
        var Allhubs = JsonArray.Parse(jsonString);
        //Read json file, and deserialization the json string to Hubcontrol class. 
        List<Hubcontrol> hubsources = new List<Hubcontrol>();
        foreach (IJsonValue jsonValue in Allhubs)
        {
            if (jsonValue.ValueType == JsonValueType.Object)
            {
                JsonObject hubcontrolitem = jsonValue.GetObject();
                hubsources.Add(new Hubcontrol()
                {
                    Title = hubcontrolitem.GetNamedString("Title"),
                    Length = hubcontrolitem.GetNamedString("Length"),
                    Features = hubcontrolitem.GetNamedString("Features")
                });
            }
        }
        //Create a new hub control, add hubsections which title is got from json
        Hub HubFromJson = new Hub();
        foreach (Hubcontrol hubcontrolitem in hubsources)
        {
            HubSection sectionitem = new HubSection();
            sectionitem.Header = hubcontrolitem.Title;
            HubFromJson.Sections.Add(sectionitem);
        }
        root.Children.Add(HubFromJson);
    }
}

public class Hubcontrol
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
    public string Features { get; set; }
}
```

I uploaded the demo [here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/PersonalDemo/tree/master/CHub).